# About Landau's 4th problem

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Landau's 4th problem asks if $\,L_n=n^2 + 1\,$ is prime for infinitely many $n \in \Bbb{N}$. This obviously occurs only when $n$ is even.

Let's consider composite positive integers represented by
$$\,(n+1)^4+4=(n^2+1)\cdot((n+2)^2+1)=L_n\cdot L_{n+2}$$

If the number of Landau's primes was finite, let it be $L_M$ the last one, then composite positive integers $\,k^4+4\,$ ($k$ odd) should admit at least 4 distinct prime factors for each $\,k\ge M+3\,$ (notice that $\,gcd(L_n\,,L_{n+2})=1$).

**Would it be possible to prove that the above statement is false, showing that at least a value of $\,k\,$ must exist for which the distinct prime factors of $\,k^4+4\,$ are less than 4, regardless the value of M?**

For example $\,125^4+4=244140629=15377 \cdot 15877$.

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you mean $k^{4} + 4$ instead of $k^{4} + 1$?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I have corrected the question.

Comment: You want to assume $k$ is odd.  There are lots of examples where $k$ is even, and of course $L_{k-1}$ and $L_{k+1}$ are not primes.

Comment: Should we dare generalize to "$\forall n>2,\exists k$ with $(k,n)=1$, $\omega(k^n+n)<n$"?

Comment: If $k^4+4=L_{k-1}L_{k+1}$ has at most three distinct prime factors, then, since the factors are relatively prime, one of them must be a prime power. Since it differs from a square by 1, by Mihailescu's theorem it must be a prime. So proving that statement false is equivalent to Landau's problem

Comment: @Wojowu: If $k^4+4$ has at most three prime factors infinitely often, then $L_n$ is prime infinitely often. However, I don't see the converse. It might happen, for example, that whenever a large $L_{k-1}$ is prime, $L_{k+1}$ has at least three prime factors.

Comment: @AugustoSanti: It is likely that $k^4+4$ has at most three prime factors infinitely often, but proving it is probably harder than showing that $n^2+1$ is prime infinitely often. As Wojowu explained, the first statement implies the second, while it is not clear how the second statement implies the first (cf. my previous remark).

Comment: @GHfromMO That's true, apologies, I was writing that a bit hastily.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose $k^4+4=L_{k-1}L_{k+1}$ has fewer than four prime divisors. Since the factors are relatively prime, this implies that one of them is a prime power. But since $L_{k\pm 1}$ is one larger than a square, from Mihailescu's theorem (more specifically its special case when one of the powers is a square) we get that that this factor must in fact be prime. Therefore the assertion that $k^4+4$ infinitely often has at most $3$ prime factors implies Landau's 4th problem.

However (contrary to what I said in a comment), as far as I can tell, it is not equivalent to it. That said, let me present an argument that it *should* still be true. In fact, the conjecture Sylvain JULIEN dares to suggest in the comment should be true, that for any $n\geq 2$ we should have $\omega(k^n+n)<n$ infinitely often. This follows from [Schinzel's Hypothesis H](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schinzel%27s_hypothesis_H). Indeed, let $d$ be the number of irreducible factors of $x^n+n$ (which is less than $n$, since there are no linear factors, and usually is $1$, e.g. if $n$ has some prime factor of exponent one). Since $x^n+n$ has no fixed prime factors (because for $x=0$ and $x=1$ the values are relatively prime), the Hypothesis H implies those factors should be simultaneously prime infinitely often, and thus $\omega(k^n+n)=d<n$ would hold infinitely often.